# page objects in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I have a question about page objects in **selenium webdriver**. our site is very dynamic with lots of *ajax* and various authentication states. How to define each page object BUT lets say I have figured that out and defined several page objects that represent our site.

How do you handle crossing from page to page? So I get a page object for my home page and one for my account page and one for my results page. Then I need to write a test that traverses all my pages to *simulate* a user performing multiple actions.

How do you obtain a HomePage object to create a new use,  then get a account page object to go perform some simulated user actions and then get a result page object to verify those actions? Can it be done in a single script?

Answer (score 0):

this question is similar to one posted here, which may have an answer to your question: [Selenium Page Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182173/using-pageobjects-page-factory-and-webdriverwait-in-selenium-webdriver-using-ja)